# Curl post gives strange characters like åäö

Tags: php, grails, encoding, curl

I have a controller in grails with a post action. 
Now, when by php and curl trying to post to the grails contoller I get `?` placeholders for characters like `åäö`, etc.
If I create a small html form doring the same post the grails contoller receives the parameters as `åäö` and not as `?`, etc.

What is the diffrence between below and how can I get curl to act as the html form example?

curl example:

```
$x = curl_init("http://localhost/post");      
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));  
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Foo=ö");  
curl_setopt( $x, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );   
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$data = curl_exec($x);   
curl_close($x);
```

html form example:

```
<html> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form name="input" action="http://localhost/post" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<TEXTAREA NAME="Foo" COLS=10 ROWS=4 type=text>ö</TEXTAREA>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

`"UTF-8"` is not a valid value for `CURLOPT_ENCODING`. You are only allowed `identity`, `deflate` or `gzip`.  You'll need to set it in the `Content-Type` header:

```
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer. Changing the HTTP_HEADER to include also the encoding as you propose does not affect the result when testing. Still the example form and curl example behaves differently when parameters get received by the server.

Comment: @Karolina In that case, you probably need to use `urlencode` on the special characters.  `curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Foo=" . urlencode("ö"));`

Comment: Hi, That didn't work either. Short question though, isn't the contenttype specified(x-www-form-urlencoded) taking care of the urlencoding?

Comment: @Karolina No. That means that the server is expecting data in that format. It doesn't mean you're sending correctly encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use urlencode with curl_setopt

   ```
   curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Foo=' . urlencode($value));
   ```
2. Ensure that `$value` is indeed in utf-8, i.e. if it is a hand coded string literal ensure that php source code file is in utf-8.